# Questions regarding regulated functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have a few quick questions regarding regulated functions:

Firstly, I'll state the definition I have been given:

**Definition:** Let $I=[a,b]$ be a compact interval. Then $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ is called *regulated* if $\exists (f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of step functions $f_n \in S(I)$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly. ($S(I)$ denotes the set of all step functions.

$1)$ Are continuous functions regulated?

$2)$ Are piecewise-continuous functions regulated?

$3)$ Are step functions regulated?

A brief explanation for each would be appreciated.

I'm hoping the answer to all three is "yes" as that would mean I have understood a few key concepts in my real analysis course.

What I'm aiming for is:

$C(I)\subset PC(I) \subset R(I)$ and $S(I)\subset PC(I)$

Where $C(I)$ denotes the set of all continous functions, $PC(I)$ denotes the set of all piecewise continuous functions and $R(I)$ denotes the set of all regulated functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?  What has you stuck?  What is your definition of regulated.  (I'm aware of two equivalent definitions.  An explanation would require reference to your definition.)

Comment: I've made an edit for the definition. I'm not stuck, I'm just double checking if these are the case. I'm pretty sure they are, but I need confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) the answer is Yes. To see this let $f$ continuous and let $I=[0,1]$. Take any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $\delta_n > 0$ be such that the condition $x,y\in I \wedge |x-y|<\delta_n $ implies $|f(x) -f(y) |\leq \frac{1}{n} .$ Let $k_n \in\mathbb{N} $ be such that $\frac{1}{k_n}<\delta_n ,$ let us define $$f_n (t) =f(1)+\sum_{j=1}^{k_n } f\left(\frac{j-1}{k_n}\right)\chi_{\left[\frac{j-1}{k_n} ,\frac{j}{k_n}\right)} (t) .$$ 
It is easy to see that $$|f_n (t)-f(t)|\leq \frac{1}{n} \mbox{ for } x\in I$$ hence $f_n $ converges to $f$ uniformly.